# Next Auth - Login error - Inconsistent query result: Field user is required to return data, got `null` instead

Tags: next.js, prisma, next-auth

I'm using Next Auth on my project and so far I created this simple login page only:

```
next 13.1.2
next-auth 4.18.8
prisma 4.9.0
@next-auth/prisma-adapter 1.0.5
```

**pages/app**

```
import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import '../style.css'

const App = ({ Component, pageProps: { session, ...pageProps } }: AppProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      <SessionProvider session={session}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </SessionProvider>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

**pages/index**

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import { signIn, signOut, useSession } from 'next-auth/react'

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const { data } = useSession()

  console.log('data', data)

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => signIn('google')}>Sign In</button>
        <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign Out</button>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

**lib/prismadb.ts**

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

declare global {
  var prisma: PrismaClient | undefined
}

const client = globalThis.prisma || new PrismaClient()
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') globalThis.prisma = client

export default client
```

**pages/api/auth[...nextauth]**

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'
import { PrismaAdapter } from '@next-auth/prisma-adapter'
import prisma from '../../../lib/prismadb'

export default NextAuth({
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    }),
  ],
})
```

My schema.prisma is taken from https://next-auth.js.org/adapters/prisma and adapted to MongoDB

So I basically followed the tutorial on the https://next-auth.js.org and then tried to run the app to check the login functionality, however when using my google account I'm getting this error:

```
[next-auth][error][adapter_error_getUserByAccount] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#adapter_error_getuserbyaccount

Invalid `p.account.findUnique()` invocation in
C:\[PATH]\client\node_modules\@next-auth\prisma-adapter\dist\index.js:11:45

   8 getUserByEmail: (email) => p.user.findUnique({ where: { email } }),
   9 async getUserByAccount(provider_providerAccountId) {
  10     var _a;
→ 11     const account = await p.account.findUnique(
Inconsistent query result: Field user is required to return data, got `null` instead. {
 ...


[next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_HANDLER_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_handler_error

Invalid `p.account.findUnique()` invocation in
C:\[PATH]\client\node_modules\@next-auth\prisma-adapter\dist\index.js:11:45

   8 getUserByEmail: (email) => p.user.findUnique({ where: { email } }),
   9 async getUserByAccount(provider_providerAccountId) {
  10     var _a;
→ 11     const account = await p.account.findUnique(
Inconsistent query result: Field user is required to return data, got `null` instead. 
...
  name: 'GetUserByAccountError',
  code: undefined
```

The strange thing is that I tested that with three google accounts, two works just fine and one gives out this error.

Frontend shows "Try signing in with a different account."

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you update anything recently? Also please post your Prisma schema.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this error dropping the Account collection from MongoDB and running the `npx prisma db push` command

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34681673)

Comment: I followed Erick suggestion and i got it to work, in my case, I removed/dropped the Account mysql table, and then ran `npx prisma db push`, and then retried my auth provider and i was able to authorize successfully.

I'm using:
`"@prisma/client": "^5.7.1",
"@next-auth/prisma-adapter": "^1.0.5",
"prisma": "^5.7.1"`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and found a work around. I'm using:

```json
"@next-auth/prisma-adapter": "^1.0.5",
"@prisma/client": "^4.11.0",
"next-auth": "^4.19.2",
```

#### Context

The error started when I tried pushing changes to my schema using `npx prisma db push`. I noticed this warning but decided to disregard it: "you are about to drop the "user" table, which is not empty..."

Since my only has a single record in it I pushed anyways. I got this error, but then realized that I had accidentally removed the `@@map("user")` flag at the bottom of my `User` model, and thought this would obviously explain the error since that flag alters the name in the db. So I added it back, thinking this would fix the problem but it didn't.

So, I went to next-auth and found this base schema for the prisma adapter that doesn't user the `@@map` flags:

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider     = "mysql"
  url          = env("DATABASE_URL")
  relationMode = "prisma"
}

model Account {
  id                 String  @id @default(cuid())
  userId             String
  type               String
  provider           String
  providerAccountId  String
  refresh_token      String?  @db.Text
  access_token       String?  @db.Text
  expires_at         Int?
  token_type         String?
  scope              String?
  id_token           String?  @db.Text
  session_state      String?

  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])
}

model Session {
  id           String   @id @default(cuid())
  sessionToken String   @unique
  userId       String
  expires      DateTime
  user         User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}

model User {
  id            String    @id @default(cuid())
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
}

model VerificationToken {
  identifier String
  token      String   @unique
  expires    DateTime

  @@unique([identifier, token])
}
```

I pushed this up and got the same warnings about dropping the x, y, z table. But since we aren't configuring the schema with the maps this shouldn't matter, and its fixed.

So it seems like something when weird when I removed the mapping and then tried to add it back. Try this and let me know what happens.